# Remove non-digit character

Tags: php, regex

How do I convert

```
(123) 456-6789 to 123456789.
```

Basically I want to strip away any non-digit character in the string.

A php example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have the keywords: `PHP`, `regex` and `non-digit` put them together into google and you will find your answer.

Comment: Can you just replace `\D+` with nothing, or are you asking how to use php's regex function calls?

Comment: thanks for the help. I had already figured it out but the online tester I was using didn't display the result I was expecting. Therefore, the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/\D+/', "", "(123) 456-6789"); // => 123456789
```

Reads *replace occurrences of non-digit characters with empty string in `"(123) 456-6789"`*.